# WPF application is unable to show the image

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and is going thru a tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw&list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M&index=2

I follow exactly the same steps, but images are not loaded in my application. What I am doing  wrong?

Note : Folder contains the said image. When I run the application, it only shows text "Some folder" but not the icon ( where as the same coding in the tutorial shows the image ).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTreeView.MainWindow"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="FolderView">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Image Width="20" Margin ="3"  Source="Images/drive.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Some folder"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfTreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(var drive in System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
            {
                var item = new TreeViewItem();
                FolderView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I duplicate your code in new wpf project and it works. Did you create "Images" folder and add picture in Solution Explorer? Maybe you have bad picture?

Comment: Make sure that Images is a folder in your Visual Studio project, the folder contains the image file, and the Build Action of the file is set to Resource.

Comment: Thanks @Klo for reverting.  After reading your answers, I re-wrote the code and found that I had a warning about declaration xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeView". As a potential fix, editor offered to remove this line. After removing the line, I got the images. Appreciate your efforts in responding. I will be glad to know what is the issue with this declaration.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, the issue was with declaration xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeView". Editor suggested to remove this and it worked. Thanks for reverting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Klo and Clemens for reverting.
I tried to re-write the code, editor had a warning for declaration xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeView"
As a suggestion, it offered to remove this line. Post removal the icons appeared again.
Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question or add comment rather than posting it as an answer